# dd operation not permitted, how to escape sandbox?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to recover a bad sector on my disk, and in doing so, need to write over the bad sector.  Numerous sources on the web suggest using dd to do so, but doing so does not work:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 bs=512 count=1 seek=961575240
dd: /dev/disk1: Operation not permitted
$
```

I figured maybe there was some sort of check about doing this to a mounted filesystem, so I booted into single-user mode (which at least leaves is in read-only mode), but I still get the same error.  Some additional messages about sandboxing are also displayed however.

```
Sandbox: dd(5) System Policy: deny(1) file-write-data /dev/disk1
Sandbox: dd(5) System Policy: deny(1) file-write-data /dev/disk1
```

Is there a way to allow dd out of the sandbox?  I tried

```
sudo sandbox-exec -p '(version 1) (allow default)' /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 bs=512 count=1 seek=961575240
```

but that still gave the operation not permitted error.

This is on OS X 10.11 GM

Comment: Do you have anything mounted on /dev/disk1 (even if it is a different sector)?  That sounds like it is a disk.  You might want to try writing to the partition (with the appropriate offset) if the partition is not mounted.  Never try to alter content of a mounted partition, even if it is read-only.  Kernels might not like it (so you may have system instability).  Note: a lot of people, myself included, state that once a drive gives a single error, you should no longer trust the drive; such drives tend to go very bad more quickly than average drives that haven't had a first disk error.  Backup!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a sacrificial computer to test this on, but I think you're running into the [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) feature in El Capitan. Mostly, what SIP does is prevent you (even as root) from modifying system areas of the disk (/System, /sbin, /bin/ most of /usr, etc), messing with system processes, loading improperly signed kexts, etc. But in order to enforce that protection of system folders, it also prevents raw writes to the device the system volume is on. Yes, even if you're root (that's the point -- it's to limit the damage from malware that gets root access).

I *think* this limit won't apply in [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). Hold Command-R as the computer starts, and it'll boot from a hidden emergency partition. Open Terminal (it's under the Utilities menu), and try the `dd` from there. `dd` might not exist on the recovery system (it's pretty minimal), but you can use `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/bin/dd` instead. You won't need `sudo`, you're already root.

If that doesn't work, try disabling SIP with `csrutil disable`, then rebooting normally (see [Apple's doc on configuring SIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html)). Then, when you're done, I'd recommend reenabling it -- it's a useful security feature.

Comment: Now you need a root for root. Genius /sarc

Comment: Thanks, that was quite informative.  Recovery mode/terminal did get me a bit farther along in that I didn't get permission or sandbox errors, but it was still unhappy about the device being busy, so booted off of a SD card to do the dd.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had to change my ”System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access > Terminal“ or iTerm2.

After I gave Full Disk Access to the Terminal or iTerm2 `dd`s operations were permitted without changing SIP/root or <kbd></kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>... I tried that too ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't work at all on the system disk. Maybe it works on a non-system disk.

Comment: This is the answer for anyone trying to access external disks with `dd`.

Comment: Full Disk Access for Terminal was the missing part for me to go past a "Operation not permitted" error while trying to clone between two external SSDs (the source containing Time Machine backups) !

Comment: This answer is correct. Just be aware of certain details, for example, when using dd via ssh, you have to give permissions to sshd, not the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `su`.

On linux/unix you first have to set a password for the root user like:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Then you should have enough permission to do this.

Also check if all partitions are unmounted.

Type in `mount` and check which partitions are mounted.

Then:

```
sudo umount /dev/disk1sX
```

Instead of `disk1sX` write the correct partition.

Comment: Running dd from root's shell (either booted fully or in single-user mode) gives the same result as 'sudo dd ...'.  Even running with root permission, it seems to be in the sandbox.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chown root:root /dev/disk1` ? Are you sure that you can write to /dev/disk1? It might be another issue...

Comment: I had to use `sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskNsX`